# how to save slidervalue and label value in nsuserdefaults or any other efficient way?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsuserdefaults, uislider

i have a view with one slider and a label.i am showing a countdown on label and setting time on label using slider.now suppose i have started the timer so the label's value is decreasing every minute and slider's value is also decreasing.now i want that if i close my app and then reopen the timer should be already running+label's value is according to time+slider value is according to time? here is an image what i am doing

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but storing stuff in NSUserDefaults is super easy. To save the slider's value:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:[mySlider value] forKey:@"sliderValue"];
```

To save the label's value:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[myLabel text] forKey:@"textValue"];
```

To get them back, simply reverse it:

```
[mySlider setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"sliderValue"]];
```

Personally, I wouldn't save the string representation of the time left, just the float. You can then restore the timer's text using whatever existing code you're using to convert the float value to a string representation.

Comment: where i retrieve them in the viewDidLoad method? will this still counting down.how do i save that how much time is left

Comment: where do i save values in application will terminate or in the view's dealloc method

Comment: Save and restore at convenient points in your existing architecture. I'm assuming you already have methods to set the timer and update the slider, so these seem like obvious places. It all depends on your code.